# Создание лейбла в андроид

Tags: java, android, android-widgets

Я пытаюсь сделать месенджер в android , а значит кол-во лейблов должно быть неограниченно, но я не знаю как это сделать. Пишу на java.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // создание лейбла с надпиью ""
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Каких лейблов? Для чего?

Comment: @ArtyMorris просто любого виджета
Я пишу интернет чат, когда я давлю на кнопку отправить, и должно создаваться текстовое поле с текстом которое я отправил. А я не знаю как его создавать

Comment: Тебе нужен recyclerView со списком сообщений. Отправляешь новое сообщение - просто добавляешь его в этот список. Вот гугл специально для тебя сделал - https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android#0

Comment: @Михаил то есть создавать виджеты через джаву невозможно?

Comment: @AndreiS так то разница не большая на чем писать, если только java вот еще есть пример https://kiosk-dot-codelabs-site.appspot.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0 Этот и предыдущий пример используют fairbase как бэк, для хранения - получения сообщений.